# Redactor plugin video on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, redactor, redactor.js

I've used this gem: https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails

**application.js**

```
//= require redactor-rails
//= require redactor-rails/video
```

**localhost**

```
<script src="/assets/redactor-rails/redactor.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/redactor-rails/config.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/redactor-rails/index.js?body=1"></script>
<script  src="/assets/redactor-rails/video.js?body=1"></script>
```

where redactor-rails/video.js is the video plugin [manually downloaded](http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/video/) form Redactor website.

**redactor-rails/config.js**

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var params;
  if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
    params = csrf_param + "=" + encodeURIComponent(csrf_token);
  }
  $('.redactor').redactor(
    { "imageUpload":"/redactor_rails/pictures?" + params,
      "imageGetJson":"/redactor_rails/pictures",
      "fileUpload":"/redactor_rails/documents?" + params,
      "fileGetJson":"/redactor_rails/documents",
      "path":"/assets/redactor-rails", //<--- Maybe is this?
      "css":"style.css",
      "plugins": ['video']}
  );
});
```

Everything works fine on my localhost, but it doesn't on remote server. I think is probably caused by Asset Pipeline maybe. 
On remote server console it doesn't show any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

**application.js**

```
//= require redactor-rails/redactor
//= require redactor-rails/video
//= require redactor-rails/config
```